# How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, reference-question

Converting regular expressions into (minimal) NFA that accept the same language is easy with standard algorithms, e.g. [Thompson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm). The other direction seems to be more tedious, though, and sometimes the resulting expressions are messy.

What algorithms are there for converting NFA into equivalent regular expressions? Are there advantages regarding time complexity or result size?

<sup>This is supposed to be a reference question. Please include a general decription of your method as well as a non-trivial example.</sup>

Comment: Note a [similar question over at cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/known-algorithms-to-go-from-a-dfa-to-a-regular-expression/9261#9261) which is probably not suited for our audience.

Comment: all answers use formal technique to write RE from DFA. I believe my technique by analysis is comparatively easy and objective I demonstrate in my answe: [What is the language of this deterministic finite automata?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717) I feel it would be helpful sometime. Yes, of-course sometime I myself uses formal method(Arden theorem) to write RE is question is complex like given in this example: [How to write regular expression for a DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17434694/1673391)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9205778/781723

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are several methods to do the conversion from finite automata to regular expressions. Here I will describe the one usually taught in school which is very visual. I believe it is the most used in practice. However, writing the algorithm is not such a good idea.

## State removal method

This algorithm is about handling the graph of the automaton and is thus not very suitable for algorithms since it needs graph primitives such as ... state removal. I will describe it using higher-level primitives.

#### The key idea

The idea is to consider regular expressions on edges and then removing intermediate states while keeping the edges labels consistent.

The main pattern can be seen in the following to figures. The first has labels between $p,q,r$ that are regular expressions $e,f,g,h,i$ and we want to remove $q$.

[image: p-q-r automaton]

Once removed, we compose $e,f,g,h,i$ together (while preserving the other edges between $p$ and $r$ but this is not displayed on this):

[image]

#### Example

Using the same example as in [Raphael's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2017/82):

[image: 1-2-3 automaton]

we successively remove $q_2$:

[image: 1-3 automaton]

and then $q_3$:

[image: 1 automaton]

then we still have to apply a star on the expression from $q_1$ to $q_1$. In this case, the final state is also initial so we really just need to add a star:

$$ (ab+(b+aa)(ba)^*(a+bb))^* $$

#### Algorithm

`L[i,j]` is the regexp of the language from $q_i$ to $q_j$. First, we remove all multi-edges:

```
for i = 1 to n:
  for j = 1 to n:
    if i == j then:
      L[i,j] := ε
    else:
      L[i,j] := ∅
    for a in Σ:
      if trans(i, a, j):
        L[i,j] := L[i,j] + a
```

Now, the state removal. Suppose we want to remove the state $q_k$:

```
remove(k):
  for i = 1 to n:
    for j = 1 to n:
      L[i,i] += L[i,k] . star(L[k,k]) . L[k,i]
      L[j,j] += L[j,k] . star(L[k,k]) . L[k,j]
      L[i,j] += L[i,k] . star(L[k,k]) . L[k,j]
      L[j,i] += L[j,k] . star(L[k,k]) . L[k,i]
```

Note that both with a pencil of paper and with an algorithm you should simplify expressions like `star(ε)=ε`, `e.ε=e`, `∅+e=e`, `∅.e=∅` (By hand you just don't write the edge when it's not $∅$, or even $ε$ for a self-loop and you ignore when there is no transition between $q_i$ and $q_k$ or $q_j$ and $q_k$)

Now, how to use `remove(k)`? You should not remove final or initial states lightly, otherwise you will miss parts of the language.

```
for i = 1 to n:
  if not(final(i)) and not(initial(i)):
    remove(i)
```

If you have only one final state $q_f$ and one initial state $q_s$ then the final expression is:

```
e := star(L[s,s]) . L[s,f] . star(L[f,s] . star(L[s,s]) . L[s,f] + L[f,f])
```

If you have several final states (or even initial states) then there is no simple way of merging these ones, other than applying the transitive closure method. Usually this is not a problem by hand but this is awkward when writing the algorithm. A much simpler workaround is to enumerate all pairs $(s,f)$ and run the algorithm on the (already state-removed) graph to get all expressions $e_{s,f}$ supposing $s$ is the only initial state and $f$ is the only final state, then doing the union of all $e_{s,f}$.

This, and the fact that this is modifying languages more dynamically than the first method make it more error-prone when programming. I suggest using any other method.

#### Cons

There are a lot of cases in this algorithm, for example for choosing which node we should remove, the number of final states at the end, the fact that a final state can be initial, too etc.

Note that now that the algorithm is written, this is a lot like the transitive closure method. Only the context of the usage is different. I do not recommend implementing the algorithm, but using the method to do that by hand is a good idea.

Comment: In the example, 2nd image, after removing node "2", there is an edge missing - loop edge (ab) in node A.

Comment: @Kabamaru: Fixed.  But now I think the $\varepsilon$ in the 3rd image should also be `ab`, and similarly perhaps in the final regular expression.

Comment: You can make the algorithm work for any number of initial and final states by adding a new initial $q^+$ and a new final state $q^-$, and connecting these to the original initial and final states by $\varepsilon$-edges. Now remove *all* the original states. The expression is then found at the single remaining edge from $q^+$ to $q_-$. The construction will not give loops at $q^+$ or $q_-$ as these states do not have ingoing resp. outgoing edges. Or if you are strict, they will have labels representing the empty set.

Comment: There is still a problem with the second example: before simplification the automata accepts "ba", (1, 3, 1) but after simplification it doesn't.

Answer (score 56):

#### Method

The nicest method I have seen is one that expresses the automaton as equation system of (regular) languages which can be solved. It is in particular nice as it seems to yield more concise expressions than other methods.

Let $A= (Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ an NFA without $\varepsilon$-transitions. For every state $q_i$, create the equation

$\qquad \displaystyle Q_i = \bigcup\limits_{q_i \overset{a}{\to} q_j} aQ_j \cup \begin{cases} \{\varepsilon\} &,\ q_i \in F \\ \emptyset &, \text{ else}\end{cases}$

where $F$ is the set of final states and $q_i \overset{a}{\to} q_j$ means there is a transition from $q_i$ to $q_j$ labelled with $a$. If you read $\cup$ as $+$ or $\mid$ (depending on your regular expression definition), you see that this is an equation of regular expressions.

For solving the system you need associativity and distributivity of $\cup$ and $\cdot$ (string concatenation), commutativity of $\cup$ and [Arden's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_lemma)¹:

> Let $L,U,V \subseteq \Sigma^*$ regular languages with $\varepsilon \notin U$. Then,
>
> $\qquad \displaystyle L = UL \cup V \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad L = U^*V$

The solution is a set of regular expressions $Q_i$, one for every state $q_i$. $Q_i$ describes exactly those words that can be accepted by $A$ when started in $q_i$; therefore $Q_0$ (if $q_0$ is the initial state) is the desired expression.

---

#### Example

<sup>For the sake of clarity, we denotate singleton sets by their element, i.e. $a = \{a\}$. The example is due to Georg Zetzsche.</sup>

Consider this NFA:

[image: example nfa]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_2016.tikz)]</sup>

The corresponding equation system is:

$\qquad \begin{align}
  Q_0 &= aQ_1 \cup bQ_2 \cup \varepsilon \\
  Q_1 &= bQ_0 \cup aQ_2 \\
  Q_2 &= aQ_0 \cup bQ_1
\end{align}$

Now plug the third equation into the second:

$\qquad \begin{align}
  Q_1 &= bQ_0 \cup a(aQ_0 \cup bQ_1) \\
      &= abQ_1 \cup (b \cup aa)Q_0 \\
      &= (ab)^*(b \cup aa)Q_0
\end{align}$

For the last step, we apply Arden's Lemma with $L = Q_1$, $U = ab$ and $V = (b \cup aa) \cdot Q_0$. Note that all three languages are regular and $\varepsilon \notin U = \{ab\}$, enabling us to apply the lemma. Now we plug this result into the first equation:

$\qquad \begin{align}
  Q_0 &= a(ab)^*(b \cup aa)Q_0 \cup baQ_0 \cup bb(ab)^*(b \cup aa)Q_0 \cup \varepsilon \\
      &= ((a \cup bb)(ab)^*(b \cup aa) \cup ba)Q_0 \cup \varepsilon \\
      &= ((a \cup bb)(ab)^*(b \cup aa) \cup ba)^* \qquad \text{(by Arden's Lemma)}
\end{align}$

Thus, we have found a regular expression for the language accepted by above automaton, namely

$\qquad \displaystyle ((a + bb)(ab)^*(b + aa) + ba)^*.$

Note that it is quite succinct (compare with the result of other methods) but not uniquely determined; solving the equation system with a different sequence of manipulations leads to other -- equivalent! -- expressions.

---

1. For a proof of Arden's Lemma, see [here](http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/nfa2regex.pdf).

Comment: What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Is there a bound on the size of the produced expression?

Comment: @jmite: I have no idea. I don't think I'd try to implement this (other methods seem to be more feasible in this regard) but use it as a pen-and-paper method.

Comment: Here's a Prolog implementation of this algorithm: https://github.com/wvxvw/intro-to-automata-theory/blob/master/automata/convert.pl#L424 but its `maybe_union/2` predicate could use more work (esp. wrt eliminating common prefix) to make tidier regular expressions. Another way to see this method is to understand it as translation from regex into right-linear grammar, where languages with Prolog-like unification or ML-like pattern matching make for a very good transducers, so it's not only a pen-and-paper algorithm :)

Comment: Just one question. The ε in the first equation is because Qo is a starting state or because it's a final state? Same way if i have two final states applies?

Comment: @PAOK  Check the definition of $Q_i$ above (the line); it's because $q_0$ is a final state.

Answer (score 33):

## Brzozowski algebraic method

This is the same method as the one described in [Raphael's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2017/82), but from a point of view of a systematic algorithm, and then, indeed, the algorithm. It turns out to be easy and natural to implement once you know where to begin. Also it may be easier by hand if drawing all the automata is impractical for some reason.

When writing an algorithm you have to remember that the equations must be always linear so that you have a good abstract representation of the equations, thing that you can forget when you are solving by hand.

#### The idea of the algorithm

I won't describe how it works since it is well done in [Raphael's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2017/82) which I suggest to read before. Instead, I focus on in which order you should solve the equations without doing too many extra computations or extra cases.

Starting from [Arden's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_Rule)'s ingenious solution $X=A^*B$ to the language equation $X=AX∪B$ we can consider the automaton as a set of equations of the form:

$$X_i = B_i + A_{i,1}X_1 + … + A_{i,n}X_n$$

we can solve this by induction on $n$ by updating the arrays $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{i,j}$ accordingly. At the step $n$, we have:

$$X_n = B_n + A_{n,1}X_1 + … + A_{n,n}X_n$$

and Arden's rule gives us:

$$X_n = A_{n,n}^* (B_n + A_{n,1}X_1 + … + A_{n,n-1}X_{n-1})$$

and by setting $B'_n = A_{n,n}^* B_n$ and $A'_{n,i}=A_{n,n}^*A_{n,i}$ we get:

$$X_n = B'_n + A'_{n,1}X_1 + … + A'_{n,n-1}X_{n-1}$$

and we can then remove all needs of $X_n$ in the system by setting, for $i,j<n$:

$$B'_i = B_i + A_{i,n}B'_n$$
$$A'_{i,j} = A_{i,j} + A_{i,n}A'_{n,j}$$

When we have solved $X_n$ when $n=1$, we obtain a equation like this:

$$X_1 = B'_1$$

with no $A'_{1,i}$. Thus we got our regular expression.

#### The algorithm

Thanks to this, we can build the algorithm. To have the same convention than in the induction above, we will say that the initial state is $q_1$ and that the number of state is $m$. First, the initialization to fill $B$:

```
for i = 1 to m:
  if final(i):
    B[i] := ε
  else:
    B[i] := ∅
```

and $A$:

```
for i = 1 to m:
  for j = 1 to m:
    for a in Σ:
      if trans(i, a, j):
        A[i,j] := a
      else:
        A[i,j] := ∅
```

and then the solving:

```
for n = m decreasing to 1:
  B[n] := star(A[n,n]) . B[n]
  for j = 1 to n:
    A[n,j] := star(A[n,n]) . A[n,j];
  for i = 1 to n:
    B[i] += A[i,n] . B[n]
    for j = 1 to n:
      A[i,j] += A[i,n] . A[n,j]
```

the final expression is then:

```
e := B[1]
```

#### Implementation

Even if it may seems a system of equations that seems too symbolic for an algorithm, this one is well-suited for an implementation. [<s>Here is an implementation of this algorithm in Ocaml</s> (broken link)](http://codepad.org/dbFztCCM). Note that apart from the function `brzozowski`, everything is to print or to use for Raphael's example. Note that there is a surprisingly efficient function of simplification of regular expressions `simple_re`.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: Implementation in Javascript: https://github.com/devongovett/regexgen/blob/master/src/regex.js

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. If I understand correctly, your initialisation pseudo-code assumes that for given i and j there is at most one a such that (i,a,j) is a transition. This is correct if we agree to label this transition with the regexp that matches all the letters in Σ that label transitions from i to j in the letter automaton, but then your notation a in Σ is a bit strange as it is not really a letter. If we go letter by letter we can have several transitions from i to j and have to do the union of their labels in the loop body.

Answer (score 28):

## Transitive closure method

This method is easy to write in a form of an algorithm, but generates absurdly large regular expressions and is impractical if you do it by hand, mostly because this is too systematic. It is a good and simple solution for an algorithm though.

#### The key idea

Let $R^k_{i,j}$ represent the regular expression for the strings going from $q_i$ to $q_j$ using the states $\{q_1, …, q_k\}$. Let $n$ be the number of states of the automaton.

Suppose that you know already the regular expression $R_{i,j}$ from $q_i$ to $q_j$ without the intermediate state $q_k$ (except for extremities), for all $i,j$. Then you can guess how adding another state will affect the new regular expression $R'_{i,j}$: it changes only if you have direct transitions to $q_k$, and it can be expressed like that:

$$R'_{i,j} = R_{i,j} + R_{i,k} . R_{k,k}^* . R_{k,j}$$

($R$ is $R^{k-1}$ and $R'$ is $R^k$.)

#### Example

We will use the same example as in [Raphael's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2017/82). At first, you can only use the direct transitions.

Here is the first step (note that a self loop with a label $a$ would have transformed the first $ε$ into $(ε+a)$.

$$R^0 =
\begin{bmatrix}
ε & a & b \\
b & ε & a \\
a & b & ε
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At the second step we can use $q_0$ (which is renamed into $q_1$ for us, because $R^0$ is already used for the purpose above). We will see how $R^1$ works.

From $q_2$ to $q_2$: $R^1_{2,2} = R^0_{2,2} + R^0_{2,1} {R^0_{1,1}}^* R^0_{1,2} = ε + b ε^* a = ε + ba$.

Why is that? It is because going from $q_2$ to $q_2$ using only $q_1$ as an intermediate state can be done by staying here ($ε$) or going to $q_1$ ($a$), looping there ($ε^*$) and coming back ($b$).

$$R^1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
ε & a & b \\
b & ε+ba & a+bb \\
a & b+aa & ε+ab
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can compute like that $R^2$ and $R^3$, too, and $R^3_{1,1}$ will give you the final expression because $1$ is both initial and final. Note that a lot of simplification of expressions have been done here. Otherwise the first $a$ of $R^0$ would be $(∅+a)$ and the first $a$ of $R^1$ would be $((∅+a)+ε(ε)^*a)$.

#### Algorithm

Initialization:

```
for i = 1 to n:
  for j = 1 to n:
    if i == j:
      R[i,j,0] := ε
    else:
      R[i,j,0] := ∅
    for a in Σ:
      if trans(i, a, j):
        R[i,j,0] := R[i,j,0] + a
```

Transitive closure:

```
for k = 1 to n:
  for i = 1 to n:
    for j = 1 to n:
      R[i,j,k] := R[i,j,k-1] + R[i,k,k-1] . star(R[k,k,k-1]) . R(k,j,k-1)
```

Then the final expression is (supposing $q_s$ is the initial state):

```
e := ∅
for i = 1 to n:
  if final(i):
    e := e + R[s,i,n]
```

But you can imagine it generates ugly regular expressions. You can indeed expect things like $(∅)^*+(a+(∅)^*)(ε)^*(a + ∅)$ that represents the same language as $aa$. Note that simplifying a regular expression is useful in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Without going through the details of how, it might be instructive to see what the worst case looks like. That also contains the essence of the closed-form (or more accurately: "fail-safe") solution, but I digress...

A 4-state automaton with states $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and $A$ as the start state, with transitions can be written as a fixed point system in [Kleene Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra) as follows:
$$
A ≥ a + aa\ A + ab\ B + ac\ C + ad\ D,\\
B ≥ b + ba\ A + bb\ B + bc\ C + bd\ D,\\
C ≥ c + ca\ A + cb\ B + cc\ C + cd\ D,\\
D ≥ d + da\ A + db\ B + dc\ C + dd\ D,
A,
$$
where the final $A$ indicates the "start expression" and with linear coefficients $aa, ab, ⋯, dc, dd$ and affine coefficients $a, b, c, d$. The solution being sought is the least fixed point solution of this (a fixed-point) system, for $\{A,B,C,D\}$, applied to and substituted in the start expression $A$. And ... that solution (with sharing of subexpressions) is:
$$
DD = dd^*,\\
DC = dc,\quad CD = cd\ DD,\\
DB = db,\quad BD = bd\ DD,\\
DA = da,\quad AD = ad\ DD,\\
CC = (cc + CD\ DC)^*,\\
CB = cb + CD\ DB,\quad BC = (bc + BD\ DC)\ CC,\\
CA = ca + CD\ DA,\quad AC = (ac + AD\ DC)\ CC,\\
BB = (bb + BC\ CB + BD\ DB)^*,\\
BA = ba + BC\ CA + BD\ DA,\quad AB = (ab + AC\ CB + AD\ DB)\ BB,\\
AA = (aa + AB\ BA + AC\ CA + AD\ DA)^*,\\
Yd = d,\\
Yc = c + CD\ Yd,\\
Yb = b + BC\ Yc + BD\ Yd,\\
Ya = a + AB\ Yb + AC\ Yc + AD\ Yd,\\
AA\ Ya
$$

The sub-expressions are $AA, AB, ⋯, DC, DD$, as well as $Ya, Yb, Yc, Yd$. If you want to see what the whole thing looks like, without the factoring out of the shared sub-expressions, in-line substitute everything, from top on down.

With sharing, it's cubic in the worst case, in the number of states (and variables).

This is one of the demo files in [RegEx](https://www.github.com/RockBrentwood/RegEx), over on GitHub, up to change in notation. The program of interest in there is "dfa". If you run the program on it, you'll get the original 4×4 system, with the 16 linear coefficients and 4 affine coefficients.

Given the complexity of the file - even with the expression sharing - you can begin to see why I never (yet) got around to writing a reverse convertor. You need heuristics to optimize the algebraic systems and expressions ... which is actually a problem well-suited for AI. So, I've been sorta sitting on this (RegEx is from the mid 1990's, originally posted in the comp.compilers archives), waiting for AI to come around.

If you want to try your hand at AI, this is a good case to work on it with. One application (of many) is control-flow-structure synthesis, because that's what this really is, in disguise. The states are goto-labels, the embedded state-labels are "goto's", the stars are loops, the "+"'s are branches, either deterministic, if "guarded" or non-deterministic.