# A regular expression for a given formal language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I wanted to ask if someone can help me to construct a regular expression over the alphabet $\{a,b,x\}$ for the language $L$ which is constituted by all strings containing an odd number of $a$'s, and in which between each pair of consecutive $a$'s there is an even number of $b$'s (and an arbirtary number of $x$'s).

For example, $babbxbbxabbxaabxxbax \in L$, $bab \in L$, while $abba \notin L$ and $abbbaa \notin L$.

What is the approach?

Comment: You can always come up with an automaton first -- maybe you even have one? -- and [convert it to a regular expression](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and build it step by step:

- a language with an odd number of $a$'s: $a(aa)^*$;
- between which there is an even number of $b$'s: $b^*a((bb)^*a(bb)^*a)^*b^*$;
- and an arbitrary number of $x$'s: $(b+x)^*a(x^*(bx^*bx^*)^*ax^*(bx^*bx^*)^*a)^*(b+x)^*$.