# Proving following regular expressions equal to one another?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, proof-techniques, regular-expressions

How would I go about proving the following two regular expressions are equal to one another:

```
( a + b )* a ( a + b )* b( a + b )* = (a + b)* ab(a + b)*
```

I can "see" why they are equal to one another because the second `( a + b )*` is a redundant term as the expression will always have an ab together. But how can I formalize this and show, in general, that this is true ?

Comment: Note: This question has been cross-posted to Math.SE, where it has received 2 answers. That can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646504/9754).

Answer (score 4):

Convert both regular expressions to a DFA, compute the symmetric difference of the two DFA's using a product construction, and then check whether the result accept the non-empty language.  Each of those steps is described here on this site.  See also [Does this regular expression equal this automata?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2851/755) for a very similar question.