# DFA to regular expression conversion

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I was looking at the question [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) to convert DFA to regex.

The question, I was trying to solve is:

[image]

I have got the following equations:

$Q_0=aQ_0 \cup bQ_1 \cup \epsilon$

$Q_1=aQ_1 \cup bQ_1 \cup \epsilon$

When solved, we will get $Q_0=a^*b(a \cup b)^* \cup\ \epsilon$

But my doubt is that, in the DFA starting state is also the final state so, even if we dont give any $b$, it will be accepted, if we give some $a$. But in the regex we have $b$, instead of $b^*$. Why is it so? Is it because,we have that regex $\cup$ $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Your solution for the equations is wrong (well, clearly, because the regex is wrong. It doesn't accept e.g. $aa$, which it should).

Can you detail how you solved the system?

Comment: On the first glance, I would say that your DFA accepts a very simple language, which you can easily express as a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using the solution to $Q = \alpha Q \cup \beta$ given by $Q = \alpha^* \beta$, essentially as you would go solving a system of linear equations by hand:

$$
\begin{align*}
Q_0 &= a Q_0 \cup b Q_1 \cup \epsilon \\
Q_1 &= (a \cup b) Q_1 \cup \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$
From the first equation you have $Q_0 = a^* (b Q_1 \cup \epsilon)$, the second one reduces to $Q_1 = (a \cup b)^* \epsilon = (a \cup b)^*$. Replacing $Q_1$ in $Q_0$ gives:
$$
Q_0 = a^* (b (a \cup b)^* \cup \epsilon) 
    = a^* b (a \cup b)^* \cup a^*
$$

Answer (score 0):

Every state and every item from the set $\{a,b\}$ has a transition to another state, and every state is an accepting state. Therefore, all states are equivalent and the regular expression (in your notation) is just $(a ∪ b)^*$.

The automaton in question is equivalent to the following [Kleene Algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra) fixed-point system of inequations:
$$A ≥ a A + b B + 1,\quad B ≥ a B + b B + 1,\quad A,$$
with the last item, $A$, indicating the starting expression. The least fixed point solution for $(A,B)$, substituted into the starting expression $A$ yields the regular expression in question.

As you noted, you can factor $B$:
$$A ≥ a A + b B + 1,\quad B ≥ (a + b) B + 1,\quad A.$$
You can solve for $B$. In general, the least fixed point solution to $x ≥ u x + v$, in $x$, which is denoted $μx·(ux + v)$, in Kleene algebra, is just $x = u^* v$. Thus, the reduction:
$$A ≥ a A + b B + 1,\quad B ≥ (a + b)^*,\quad A.$$
Upon substitution for $B$ and elimination, this reduces to:
$$A ≥ a A + b (a + b)^* + 1,\quad A.$$
In a similar way, we find the solution for $A$:
$$A ≥ a^* (b (a + b)^* + 1),\quad A,$$
and, upon substitution and elimination of $A$:
$$a^* (b (a + b)^* + 1).$$

(Your mistake, as already noted in another reply, is that you had the equivalent of $a^* b (a + b)^* + 1$, instead of $a^* (b (a + b)^* + 1)$.)

Kleene-algebraic identities can be used, particularly $(u + v)^* = u^* (v u^*)^*$ and $u^* = u u^* + 1$, reducing this to
$$\begin{align}
a^* (b (a + b)^* + 1)
&= a^* (b a^* (b a^*)^* + 1)\\
&= a^* (b a^*)^*\\
&= (a + b)^*,
\end{align}$$
or, in your notation $(a ∪ b)^*$.

The axioms cited in the linked article are sufficient to prove any and all Kleene-algebraic identities. They are equivalent to the following set of properties:
$$
(x + y) + z = x + (y + z),\quad x + 0 = x = 0 + x,\quad x + y = y + x,\quad x + x = x,\\
(xy)z = x(yz),\quad x 1 = x = 1 x,\quad p 0 q = 0,\quad p (x + y) q = p x q + p y q,\\
0^* = 1,\quad μx·(a + bx + xc) = b^* a c^*.
$$
(*Edit*: I put in $0^* = 1$, too, otherwise you have to split the least-fixed-point equation into $μx·(a + bx) = b^* a$ and $μx·(a + xc) = a c^*$.)

These axiomatizations come from 1994. Many texts - even now - are obsolete, still using frameworks from the 1960's and not including these more recent developments, which themselves are now over a generation past.

If you strengthen it by replacing the last axiom with
$$p (μx·f(x)) q = \sup_{n≥0} p f^n(0) q,$$
where
$$f^0(x) = x,\quad f^1(x) = f(x),\quad f^2(x) = f(f(x)),\quad f^3(x) = f(f(f(x))),\quad ⋯,$$
where $f(x)$ denotes an arbitrary Kleene-polynomial in $x$, then you get an axiomatization for fixed-point-closed Kleene algebras that is complete with respect to the algebra of context-free subsets; i.e. an algebra for "context-free" expressions: μ-continuous Chomsky Algebras.

This comes from the mid-2010's (2014, I believe) and was in 2018 proven equivalent to another axiomatization that arose in 2008 (the algebra of C-dioids), which used in place of the last property that (a) every context-free subset $U$ has a least upper bound $\sup U$, and (b) $\sup \{p\}U\{q\} = p (\sup U) q$, for context-free subsets $U$.