# Regular expression for odd binary numbers without leading zeros

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have to write a regular expression that accepts any odd binary number not preceded by a 0. the best I can come up with is $1(0\cup1)^*1$, but that doesn't match just 1. The best it matches is 11.

Comment: just add that single $1$ to your expression as an alternative to what you already have!

Comment: I had thought of that, but I worried that it would not be the minimum possible. Thanks.

Comment: Minimal length is not always better than "elegant", or "easy to understand". A short alternative could be $1(0^*1)^*$. That one has nested stars, which is more complex in some respects.

Comment: Obligatory hint: build an NFA and [convert](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions?rq=1). Also, any question should contain, well, a *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you might just add that single $1$ to your expression as an alternative to what you already have. One obtains $1 \cup 1(0\cup 1)^*1$.

An alternative is $1(0^*1)^*$. That one is shorter, but not necessarily better.

Actually that expression I obtained by starting with the FSA below, and realizing that the rightmost two states could be replaced by iterating $0^*1$.

[image]

Comment: sorry for going off-topic here, which tool you have used to draw this beautiful looking DFA ?

Comment: The diagram was made in $\LaTeX$ using the package [GasTeX](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/)

Comment: @avi I have been using this [script of mine](http://lmazy.verrech.net/tag/tikz2png/) with TikZ.