# Can we minimise regular expressions using known DFA minimisation algorithms?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Of course, converting NFA to DFA is not a problem. But what about the other direction?

My motivation is the notion of minimization regular expressions using the DFA minimization algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure you have the directions right? What you ask is trivial. A DFA is in particular an NFA. The converse, however, requires the determinization process called the "subset-construction".

Comment: The answers to your question are in wikipedia. You should do a tiny bit of research before asking. The people who answer have only 24 hours each day.

Comment: True, but that was not what I meant. DFA is also an NFA. But can be from DFA somehow restored the original regular expression? Or at least some good guess can be provided?

Comment: Many regular expressions (or many FA) can define the same regular
language and be transformed into each-other. So there is no knowing which you started from. What remains
unique, if I may say, is the language defined. Now the [minimal
DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) is also unique (up
to notations) for a given language, as it can be directly characterized
from properties of the language - see [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: fyi the problem of finding the _smallest_ NFA for a DFA is a nontrivial semi-open research question, theres another question here on that.

Comment: @vzn Can you please link it?

Comment: [computing the minimal NFA for a DFA](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/computing-the-minimal-nfa-for-a-dfa), its Pspace complete.

Answer (score 1):

You should have asked first what you wanted : your second line.
Why assume that you have to reverse the determinization procedure to
get back to a regular expression. You confused your readers. You might add it as a possible way you imagined to go about it, after you stated what you want, not before.

To find out how to get a RE from a FA, just search the web for :
"convert finite automata to regular expressions". It is an interesting topic.

If you want a "minimal regular expression", just search for that.
But I am not sure what minimal would mean (number of operators used
?).

If you want to find a "minimal NFA" search for that, but I gather it is a
rather difficult problem, still under research.

If you want a "minimal DFA", search for that. It is a well explored
problem.

Comment: As noted, NFA minimization is not so well defined. There's work that shows SAT solvers are quite good at it though. Nowadays we can also minimize DFAs in $O(m \log n)$ time, assuming the usual $n \leq 2m$.

Comment: No need to google: we have a [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) right here.

Comment: I did not say google :-) ... I try to be agnostic