# What is a regular expression that matches all strings over the alphabet except a particular substring?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I've come across this problem in my studies, and I've abstracted it to the more general case here.

Given a finite alphabet, what is a regular expression that matches all strings over the alphabet, except one particular finite substring?

As an example:

Given $\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$

What is a regular expression that matches all of $\Sigma$ except the substring $
ba$?

What I really want is simply $\Sigma^* - ba$.

Comment: In your question you state "except one particular finite **sub** string", where "sub" suggests that you are interested in $\Sigma^* - \Sigma^* ba \Sigma^*$ instead?

Comment: @HendrikJan Yes, that is what I rather meant to say, sorry about that.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any comparable example, e.g. via [tag:regular-expressions]? Can you give an NFA and [convert it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)?

Answer (score 4):

Just draw the minimal complete DFA accepting your string, change the final states to get the complement and now convert this new DFA to a regular expression.

In your case, you will get $\mathcal{A} = (Q, A, \cdot, 1, F)$ with $Q = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, $A = \{a, b, c \}$, $F = \{3\}$ and $1 \cdot b = 2$, $2 \cdot a = 3$ and $q \cdot x = 0$ for all other transitions. Thus the automaton for the complement is $\mathcal{A}' = (Q, A, \cdot, 1, F')$ with $F' = \{0, 1, 2\}$.

Converting $\mathcal{A}'$ to a regular expression gives
$$
  1 + b + (c + bc + baA)A^*
$$

Comment: I have not seen this notation of $1$ in a regular expression. And is $+$ equivalent to the union operation?

Comment: This is the algebraic notation (quite common) for a regular expression. Union is denoted by + and 1 denotes the empty word, which is the neutral element for the concatenation product: for all words u, 1u = u = u1.

Comment: In the regular expression you gave, it contains '..$baA$'. So doesn't this set (or language) represented by this regular expression obviously contain strings with ba as a substring? Furthermore, if you're doing $A^*$, you will get $ba$, $bba$, will you not?

Comment: By definition, $A = a + b + c$ and hence $baA = baa + bab + bac$. Thus $baAA^*$ is the set of all words of the form $baau$, $babu$ or $bacu$ for some word $u$. None of these words is equal to $ba$.

Comment: But they contain $ba$ as a substring. I rather meant to imply in my question that I want a regular expression for all strings over $\Sigma$ except those containing $ba$ as a substring.

Comment: The last sentence of your question clearly states "What I really want is simply $\Sigma^*− ba$" and I tried to answer this question. If the question you had in mind was different, it would be better to ask another question.

Comment: You did answer that question. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

One way of finding such a regular expression is
$$ \epsilon+a+b+c+aa+ab+ac+bb+bc+ca+cb+cc+(a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)^*. $$
There might be more succinct solutions, but this always works (for all finite languages).

Comment: I think OP means $\Sigma^*-\Sigma^*ba\Sigma^*$ as henric mentioned in his comment, otherwise as you write excluding that string is enough.

Comment: I don't see a "way" here, only a final result.

Comment: @Raphael I'm sure you can generalize this. If the maximal word omitted is of length $\ell$, I'm listing all other words of length at most $\ell$, and add $\Sigma^{\ell+1} \Sigma^*$.