# Construct a regular expression for strings over the alphabet {a, b, c} that don’t contain the contiguous substring "baa"

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I want to construct a **regular expression for strings over the alphabet {a, b, c} that don’t contain the contiguous substring "baa"**. I tried to follow the same procedure as in [all the words that don't have both substring bba and abb](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21707/how-did-they-get-this-answer-for-the-words-that-dont-have-bba-and-abb), where the goal was to find a regular expression that matches **all words that do not contain both "bba" and "abb" as substrings**. However, I got stuck at some point and could not get the correct answer. Here are the steps I followed:

Here is how I tried to solve it

1. I constructed an NFA that accepts all words that contain contiguous substring "baa"[image]
2. I constructed the **complement** of NFA by turning middle states into final states and final states into middle ones. Here it is.
   [image]
3. I simplified the NFA by adding a new final state and eliminates some states.
   [image]
4. I tried to write a regular expression for the simplified NFA, but I realized that it still accepts words that contain contiguous "baa" as a substring
   [image]

Can someone tell me where I went wrong and how to fix it? Is there a better way to approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is that at step 2 you accept baabaa on the node number 1 alone. At step 1, you could perhaps remove the transition (1, b)->1  and add the transitions (2, b)-> 2 and (2, c)->1 and also (3, b)->2 and (3, c)-> 1 etc, (4,a)->1, (5,b)->2, (6,b)->2

Answer (score -1):

I find it easier to build a DFA directly in this case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should construct DFA not NFA