# Converting DFA to Regular Expression "equation-method(?)"

Tags: automata

I have trouble understanding my text-book on how to convert a DFA to a Regular Expression using "equation-method"(don't no what it's called).
If someone could explain step by step in detail what's going on it would be great(or maybe a few steps to get me going). (Old exam-task)

I have this DFA:

[image]

And the solution is:

[image]

I think I understand the left column.
First expression in left column: $E_0 = 0E_1 + 1E_2$. $E_0$ is a regular expression that "represents the start-state $q_0$". You can choose two paths from $q_0$. On a zero you go to $q_1$ (Zero concatenated with the regular expression $E_1$).
Or on a one you go to $q_2$ (one concatenated with the regular expression $E_2$).
And the same principle goes for the rest of the column. How do I continue from this?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Please see our [reference  question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) for detailed explanations of such methods. If you still have questions after reading the material there, please update your question to reflect what you tried (further) and where you got stuck.

Comment: Adding to Raphael's comment: The method used in your example appears to be the one in his answer to the reference question.