# Regex: Any pair of zeros is before any pair of ones

Tags: regular-expressions

Write a regular expression for all the strings in which every pair of adjacent zeros appears before any pair of adjacent ones. The answer given in the book is:
$$(0+10)^*(00)(1+01)^*(11)(0+10)^*(1+01)^*$$
Is that correct? I fail to see how could you get a string like **10011**, but it fits description. I mean even a string like **1** fits a description. So, if this answer is incorrect, then what is a correct answer?
My simple guess is:
$$(\epsilon+1)(0+10)^*(1+01)^*(\epsilon+0)$$

P.S.
Does $(0^*1^*)^*$ generate every possible binary number? If not, what does it generate?

Comment: Not to mention that the book answer won't generate **11**.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, since it generates $1100$.

Comment: My guess is $(0+10)^*(1+10)^*$.

Comment: For languages such as this, it's sometimes easier to construct an NFA and [convert it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions). That siad, I'm confused by "every" and "any" (note that title != text). For instance, is $00$ forbidden after $11$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the regexp you quote does not match the string $10011$ and that string has the property that every pair of adjacent $0$s occurs before any pair of adjacent $1$s.  But it does match the string $001100$, which fails to have the property!

Your proposed solution matches $11001$ so is also incorrect (the first bracket matches $1$, the second matches $10$, the third matches $01$ and the fourth matches $\epsilon$.

A regexp that does match the required language is
$$0^*(100^*)^*(11^*0)^*1^*\,.$$
It works as follows.

- $0^*(100^*)^*$ matches the empty string and any non-empty string that doesn't contain $11$ and that ends with $0$. The string can't contain $11$ because there must be at least one $0$ between every two $1$s.
- $(11^*0)^*1^*$ matches every string that begins with $1$ and does not contain $00$, since there must be at least one $1$ between any two $0$s.
- Now put the two halves together. If a string has the property that all occurrences of $00$ are before the first $11$, then the section of the string before the first $11$ must either be empty or end in $0$, so it matches the first part of the regexp. The rest of the string contains no occurrences of $00$ so it matches the second part of the regexp.

Note that there are shorter regexps that do the same thing: Yuval Filmus gives $(0+10)^*(1+10)^*$ in a comment to the question. That's a tidier version of the same idea.

And, yes, $(0^*1^*)^* \equiv (0+1)^*$ matches every possible binary string.

Comment: Can you please give me the name of your texbook you got that answer from?

Comment: I didn't get it from any textbook and I'm kind of insulted that you think that I'd (a) not be able to solve this for myself and (b) not credit the source of the answer if I had taken it from somewhere else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Doesn't $(0+10)^*(1+10)^*$ generate the strings like $0010$? And $1$ is not in pair here.

Answer (score 0):

(0011)* ((^ + 0)(1+101+10011)(1+01+0011))*(^+0)
Regex: {0,1} :Every pair of adjacent zeros appears before any pair of adjacent ones('^'->null).

Comment: In 1001110011, one pair of adjacent zeros appears after two pairs of adjacent ones.

Comment: The question says "any pair of adjacent 1's". So pair of 1's is not the concern. Adjacent 0's must appear before ANY PAIR OF ADJACENT 1's.

Comment: See [Raphael's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34025/regex-any-pair-of-zeros-is-before-any-pair-of-ones/155561?noredirect=1#comment69061_34025) (the question's wording is unfortunate) and [David Richerby's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/34027/19966).

Comment: Yes , I agree with the confusion but I am pretty sure the question in the text ("every pair of adjacent 0's") is the correct one, while the question in the title ("any pair of 0's") was written haste or brief. Nevertheless, the regex for "Every pair of adjacent 0's appearing before any pair of adjacent 1's" is correct.