# What is the procedure for converting this finite automaton into a regular expression?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

Could someone provide an explanation of how to convert this DFA into a regular expression? I have found three methods online, ie: [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)

but they are all very confusing to me.

The automaton is:

$$M = ((1,2,3), 1, \{a,b\}, \delta, \{1,3\})$$ 
where

$$\delta(1,a) = 2\\
\delta(1,b) = 2\\
\delta(2,a) = 2\\
\delta(2,b) = 3\\
\delta(3,b) = 2\\
\delta(3,a) = 1$$

Comment: What part is causing the confusion? I also suggest starting with the state removal method, it's simple and visual (but easy to miss things in larger automata).

Comment: wrt to the state removal method, I am not sure how to assign the arrows after removing some state.

Comment: Given a state to remove $w$, you look at every ordered pair $u$, $v$ of remaining states, and see if there was a set of transitions $u\rightarrow w$ labelled with $r_{1}$, $w \rightarrow w$ labelled with $r_{2}$ and $w \rightarrow v$ labelled with $r_{3}$, if there is, then after removing $w$, add a transtion $u\rightarrow v$ labelled with $r_{1}r_{2}^{\ast}r_{3}$.

Comment: The reference question you found contains examples for all methods. It is not clear what your problem is, and how it can be solved without reproducing content from the reference question here (needlessly). (I don't consider just solving the exercise for you likely to be of help.)