# Regular expression - every b preceded and followed by an even number of a's

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to write a regular expression over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$ for the language in which every $b$ is preceded and followed by an even number of $a$'s.

I think the regular expression should include something like $((aa)^*b(aa)^*)^*$ but I don't know how to extend it in order to get to the correct form. Can anyone help me by providing a step-by-step solution?

Comment: What makes you think the expression you have won't cover it? The only case I can see you missing is a word with an odd number of $a$s but no $b$s.

Comment: @jmite I think I'm missing the cases in which I only have $a$'s, no mather if their number is odd or even.

Comment: This question seems to be covered by the combination of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2016/755.  Is there any reason why I should not close this question as a duplicate of one of those?

Comment: @D.W. I don't see how those two questions are similar to this one since I'm not trying to prove that my language is regular or to convert a finite automaton to a regular expression.

Comment: @Eduard, the first link explains how to build a NFA for the language; the second link explains how to turn the NFA into a regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you already have covers almost all the cases: any time there's a $b$, there need to be an even number of $a$'s, so that covers all words containing a $b$.

However, there's an edge case where there are no $b$'s in your word, so you need to union your language with the case where the word has no $b$'s.

$((aa)^*b(aa)^*)^* \cup a^*$ should fit your final answer.