# What is the complexity of finding a regular expression equivalent to a given DFA?

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, regular-expressions, search-problem

I had taken a course long ago on complexity theory. I only remember basic things,
so I am reading "Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser". The book in its first chapter introduces DFA and NFA.

If we are given a DFA $D$ where $\sum=\{0,1\}$ ( the alphabets ), then how difficult is the  problem of finding a regular expression of the language that $D$ recognises?

By difficulty I mean to which class does this problem belong like NP,PSPACE etc ( sorry for vague definition of difficulty, I only have a broad understanding of what classes NP,PSPACE etc are as of now ).

Comment: What do you mean, "identify"? Given a regular expression and a DFA, decide if they describe the same language? Or given a DFA, compute an equivalent regular expression?

Comment: @Raphael The second one. Given a DFA compute equivalent regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Find an equivalent regular expression" is not a *decision problem*, so it can not be in any of these classes. See also [our reference questions on complexity theory](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/845#845).

There are [polynomial-time algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) that solve your computational problem, though, so it is in some flavor of P.