# Step by step method for generating Regular Expressions for languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I was wondering if there was a method that can be used to generate a Regular Expression for a language.
Take the Language $L$ as an example where:

$L= \{w \in \{0, 1\}^{\ast} \mid \text{length of } w \text{ is a multiple of } 2 \text{ or } 3\}.$

Can you show the step by step method to make the `RE` for this language?
Cheers

Comment: In general? No, because that would imply you could algorithmically decide whether a given language is regular (impossible). Of course, there are certain methods, e.g. [build an NFA](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51811/) and [convert it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions). (Community votes, please: duplicate?)

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let's denote $w_{\text{two}}$ words with length that is a multiple of $2$

and $w_{\text{three}}$ words with length that is a multiple of $3$

So think about:

$$|w_{\text{three}}|\bigg|_{3}\cup|w_{\text{two}}|\bigg|_{2}$$