# Regular expression at least 2 out of 3 consecutive characters should be 1

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

How can I build a regular expression that, using only the concatenate, union and star operations, over the alphabet {0,1}, describes the language "Every three consecutive characters contain at least two 1, and the input has length at least 3"? For instance 110011, 0101 and 11 should be refused. I was thinking on using the logic from this (incomplete) DFA, but I can't figure out how to get a regular expression that follows the rule. Thanks! [image]

Comment: You can use [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2016/23039) to transform a finite automaton to a regular expression.

Comment: That automaton can't be correct since it accepts all strings of length one.

Comment: That's why I stated it was incomplete, I ommited the successive transitions from the initial state that lead to one of the four states above. I just wanted to show the behaviour the regulard expression should have once it reaches that point.

Comment: @Camil all the examples I have seen using this method seem to be limited to a single accept state.

Comment: [The first answer to that question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2389/23039) says: "If you have several final states (or even initial states) then there is no simple way of merging these ones, other than applying the transitive closure method." [One of the other answers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2395/23039) to that question describes this method.

Comment: @Evil Sorry I forgot to specify "at least" two 1s, I will edit this right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that string $s$ is in $L$. We will look at the last two characters of the string:

- `00`, impossible, because this string could not be in $L$.
- `01`, next character must be 1, new last two characters is `11`.
- `10`, next character must be 1, new last two characters is `01`.
- `11`, next character may be 1 or 0, new last two characters is `10` or `11`.

Note that no matter your current state, you will always pass through the `11` state within two steps. Assuming that $s$ ended with `11`, we get the following loop:

```
(1|(011))*
```

This will be the middle section of any string in $L$. All we need to do now is handle possible prefixes, making sure not to allow any with size < 3:

```
(111|011|1011|11011)
```

And finally, possible suffixes (note the empty union to express that the suffix is optional):

```
(|0|01)
```

Now all that's left is to concatenate them:

```
(111|011|1011|11011)(1|(011))*(|0|01)
```

Comment: Thanks! We would just need to add 101|110|1101|(your expression).