# Help with this FSA please :(

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

[image][image]
I have to convert this fsa to regular expression but these are too different than i learned... Can you guys help with converting these? Plz!

Comment: Use an [algorithm](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions). The task may become arduous, but never hard.

Comment: I didn't learned those yet as i'm a beginner i'm still doing these with on paper things :(