# How to convert DFA to regular expression using arden's rule

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata, formal-languages

I generally use state removal method to convert DFA to regular expressions. But I want to try other methods like using algebraic methods and arden's rule.

How to solve a DFA with multiple final states using algebraic method?
I refered this link
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions and arrived at this solution which I think is wrong since a can be followed by only a or c not b.

[image: DFA]

[image: solution]

I used state removal method and arrived at below regular expression which seems to be correct as the language won't contain ab.

[image: state removal method]

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are wrong; your solution works for the reversed arrows. You should be solving the following system:
$$
q_0 = (b+c)q_0 + aq_1 + \epsilon \\
q_1 = cq_0 + aq_1 + \epsilon
$$