# What is the regular expression for strings containing at least one a and at least one b?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

$L = \{w \in \{a, b, c\}^*\mid w\text{ contains at least one }a\text{ and at least one }b\}$.

what's the proper regular expression for the following language?

Comment: Start with a regular expression for strings which contain, at some point, an $a$, and at a later point, a $b$.

Answer (score -1):

The DFA of this language can be easily written.

Apply state removal method to this machine, then you can receive a regular expression.

Reference to state removal method: [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2016/87203)