# DFA multiple accepting states to Regular expression

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to find the regular expression that defines this DFA, I am finding this particular case difficult since it has multiple accepting states.

If I understand this DFA correctly, it recognises:

empty strings or strings with any number of `b` => `b*`

or

`a` followed by any number of `b` => `ab*`
or
`aa` followed by any number of `b` => `aa(b*)`

So the closest I have got is `b*+(a+aa)+(a+aa)b*` but I know this is not correct, since it doesn't recognise strings such `aabaabab`.

[image]

I have been using http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/ so I can see I don't know how to make the transition back to  `Q0` from `Q1` or `Q2` when there is a `b`.

I took a look to [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) but the explanations are way above my current level of understanding.

Could anybody help me finding where I'm going wrong and how could I fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If all else fails, you can always construct three separate regular expressions $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$ that correspond respectively to the automata where just the first, second and third state is accepting. And then take $R_1+R_2+R_3$.

Comment: Note that you can have arbitrarily long blocks of `b`s alternating with blocks of one or two `a`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DFA accepts all words not containing $aaa$. Such words are built of the following "building blocks": $b,ab,aab$. Additionally, a word may end with $a,aa$. In total, we get the regular expression
$$
(b+ab+aab)^*(\epsilon+a+aa).
$$

Comment: Many many  thanks! 
When discussing it with a colleague I was told I shouldn't use the ``, only `*` to indicate a string of any length (including the empty string) however, I am not sure it is possible to do it in this particular case.
In any case I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can use the distributive rule to get rid of $\epsilon$, but I don't really see the point of it. I'm not sure you understood your colleague correctly.

Comment: I guess the point she made was that `(b + )*` is equivalent to `(b)*` and that I shouldn't use ``, but as you said, there's no point as long as the regex works.

Comment: This point doesn’t seem relevant here.

Comment: Agreed, many thanks again Yuval.