# How generate regular expression on the alphabet {a,b}?

Tags: regular-expressions

How can I write a regular expression that denotes language on the alphabet {a,b}  of the strings that do not present "b" consecutive and the total number of "a" is multiple of three?.

Comment: Construct a DFA/NFA for your language, and then convert it into a regular expression.

Comment: Just make sure that you either add three a's (as many times you want with the kleene operator) or add an b and immediately 3 a's. Try to write this as a RegEx yourself

Comment: Check [_how to convert finite automata to regular expressions_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).