# Converting DFA to RE

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I have been trying to solve this problem.

Convert the DFA to a regular expression. [image]

I extracted these following equation.

$q_1 = q_2a$

$q_2 = q_1a + (a+b)q_3$

$q_3 = q_1b + q_2a $

Also,the solution is 
$a(aa)^*+a^*b((a+b)a^*b)^*+a^*b((a+b)a^*b)^*(a+b)(aa)^*$

Can somebody tell me how to get to this answer??

Comment: Did you already had a look at the [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)?

Comment: @ttnick yes, but I got a different answer..