# Converting DFA to RE with Arden's Rule

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

So I've searched around and found the algorithm to do so: [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions?newreg=57b7b61a9a734a09b16159449a2476f2) and I decided to test out the second-level response, Raphaels, and while I was getting correct regexes at least to my knowledge, I was having some weird issues with variables/state names. Please help me understand what my mistake is here in my process:

Consider the DFA that is governed by these equations and $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$:
$$Q_0 = bQ_2 \cup aQ_1
\\ Q_1 = bQ_2 \cup aQ_0
\\ Q_2 = aQ_2 \cup bQ_2 \cup \varepsilon$$

I'm sorry I don't have a picture of the graph, but I think this should be fairly simple to visualize. It is an unminimized DFA that pretty much accepts every string with at least 1 'b', as it bounces back and forth from $Q_1$ and $Q_0$ every time an 'a' is reached, both $Q_1$ and $Q_0$ have edges to $Q_2$ from 'b', and $Q_2$ is an accept state that stays at $Q_2$ no matter what character it sees. Now I attempt to do the reduction method we see in Raphael's post:

$Q_1 = bQ_2 \cup a(bQ_2 \cup aQ_1)
\\ Q_1 = bQ_2 \cup abQ_2 \cup aaQ_1
\\ Q_1 = (b \cup ab)Q_2 \cup aaQ_1
\\ Q_1 = (aa)^*(b \cup ab)Q_2$

$\\ Q_2 = a^*bQ_2 \cup \varepsilon
\\ Q_2 = a^*b^* \cup \varepsilon
\\ Q_2 = (a^*b^*)^*$

$\\ \\ Q_1 = (aa)^*(b \cup ab)(a^*b^*)^*$

Now I have two questions here:

1. Notice that at the end of my $Q_1$ manipulation I moved $(aa)^*$ to the front. This is something that I did out of common sense since thinking about the DFA, $(aa)^*$ *has* to be first since $Q_2$ doesn't have any outbound edges. Is there a way to formalize what I'm thinking/doing here?
2. Notice that at the end I have my valid regex equal to $Q_1$. That doesn't seem right, since we want to find the regex associated with $Q_2$! But a quick simulation through my head tells me that it actually is the regex associated with $Q_2$. So what is going on?!

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: In addition to D.W.'s comment below, I figured out that I was pretty much just skipping a step for my first question: it should be $Q_1 = (b \cup ab)Q_2 \cup aaQ_1 \Rightarrow Q_1 = aaQ_1 \cup (b \cup ab)Q_2 \Rightarrow Q_1 = (aa)^*(b \cup ab)Q_2$. This makes my application of Arden's Rule valid here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manipulation where you went from $Q_1 = (b \cup ab)Q_2 \cup aaQ_1$ to $Q_1 = (aa)^*(b \cup ab)Q_2$ was not valid.  Instead, in this case I suggest that you first start by finding a nice form for $Q_2$, before trying to manipulate $Q_1$.

A good way to handle $Q_2$ is to note that $Q_2 = a Q_2 \cup b Q_2 \cup \epsilon$ implies $Q_2 = (a \cup b) Q_2 \cup \epsilon$ (by the distribute law); when then apply Arden's rule to conclude that $Q_2 = (a \cup b)^* \epsilon = (a \cup b)^*$.

Now plug in this expression for $Q_2$ into your equations for $Q_0$ and $Q_2$.  You obtain

$$\begin{align*}
Q_0 &= b (a \cup b)^* \cup a Q_1\\
Q_1 &= b (a \cup b)^* \cup a Q_0
\end{align*}$$

Next, take the expression for $Q_1$ and plug it into the first equation.  We see that

$$Q_0 = b (a \cup b)^* \cup a b (a \cup b)^* \cup a a Q_0.$$

Now applying Arden's rule tells us that

$$Q_0 = (aa)^* (b \cup ab) (a \cup b)^*.$$

That's the regular expression that you ultimately wanted.

Comment: Great, thank you for clearing my confusion about applying Arden's rule. A quick question though, in your solution, we have $Q_0$ = (the regex we want). However, in my hypothetical DFA, $Q_2$ is the accept state, so shouldn't we be getting a regex for $Q_2$? Or are we trying to find a regex for the start state of the machine? Thanks so much.

Comment: @CoolRobloxKid12, nope.  The regexp that we get for $Q_0$ is the regexp that describes all strings that are accepted by the DFA, if you use $Q_0$ as the initial state of the DFA.  That's what we want.  The regexp we get for $Q_2$ describes all strings accepted by the DFA if you start at state $Q_2$ as your initial state.  That's not what we want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess as a consequence to this then is that substituting for $Q_1$ producing the same regex is just a coincidence based on the way this DFA has been set up. Thank you so much for the help