# Formal Binary String Regular Expression (each pair of 00 must have 11 before it)

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to construct a regular expression for the language of binary strings in which every 00 must have at least two 1s before it.

I realize this can be done with lookbehinds using the following regex: `^(?:(?<=11)00(?!0)|(?<=1)0|1+)+$` , however I am now trying to construct a regular expression in the sense of formal language theory.

I currently have `(0|)(11*0)*1*` (or `(0+ε)(11*0)*1*` ), which gives me the language of binary strings without consecutive 0s, but am not quite sure how to get the 'conditional' part in without actually using a conditional.

**Accepted:**
0
1
10
11100
1100

**Rejected:**
100
1000
11000

Comment: What is the "conditional", in your opinion? It's easy enough to do alternation, and nothing requires alternation to be exclusive: $(0|)(111^*00|11^*0)^*1^*$

Comment: by 'conditional' i was referring to the 'if there is 00, there must at least 2 1s' condition. i am still trying to wrap my head around this all, i am curious what type of approach you used to come up with that expression, is there a technique I can use to derive a formal regex from a language?

Comment: Regular expressions don't have conditionals so you need to come up with a different way of thinking about them. As I said, alternation works so one approach is to enumerate possibilities, which is what I did: 00 must follow two or more 1s; a single 0 must follow one or more 1s (otherwise it wouldn't be a single 0).

Comment: `^(?:(?<=11)00(?!0)|(?<=1)0|1+)+$` does not match those strings that start with 0, such as 0, or 01, or 010, etc. It also misses the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to describe a binary string in which every 00 must have at least two 1s before it.

It is a string that
$\quad$ starts with zero or one 0;
$\quad$ followed by zero or more blocks, where each block is
$\quad\quad$ either one or more 1s followed by a 0, such as 10, 110, 1110, etc,
$\quad\quad$ or two or more 1s followed by two 0s, such as 1100, 11100, 111100, etc;
$\quad$ followed by zero or more 1s.

Translated into regular expression, the description above becomes
$\quad$ `(0|ε)(11*0|111*00)*1*`

---

You might want to ask, how can we arrive that kind of description?

The observation here is that the number of consecutive 0s in the string is at most 2, a very small number. That indicates that we can break down the string by enumerate different possibilities of consecutive 0s. To paraphrase [rici's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134820/formal-binary-string-regular-expression-each-pair-of-00-must-have-11-before-it#comment283976_134820), we could try using enumeration to simulate conditionals.

---

Of course, there is a mild stroke of luck involved in the approach above on that language.  As a last resort, we can always use a heavier machinery such as constructing a DFA for the language (which can be done in one or several ways) and then [converting the DFA to a regular expression](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).