# Convert the Finite Automata (FSA) into its equivalent regular expression, using stepwise minimization

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I was doing an assignment of Theory of automata but while doing this question I am stuck there is no such state that can be eliminated even from transition table. I am very confused and stuck please help me out

[image]

Comment: The accepting state can be changed to $(a\cup b)^*$ for example

Comment: The current DFA is already minimal, so you will not find any state to remove into a smaller DFA. What you can do, however, is remove states by transforming labels on transition from letters to regular expressions. The method is described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2389/79440).