# Converting Deterministic Finite Automata to Regular Expression

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions, theory

I am reading Michael Sipser's "Theory of Computation". In one of the proofs he talks about converting "DFA to Regular Expression" and he talks about "GNFAs". I understand one method of converting DFA to Regular Expression that is using Arden's Theorem. I assume GNFA is a medium between DFA and Regular Expression. Can someone explain the GNFA method? and also would i be okay not knowing it and only knowing the Arden Theorem method?

Comment: The GNFA is a finite automaton with regular expressions along the edges, instead of single symbols. On this site a summary is given under the name [state removal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2389/4287) method. This method is mostly equivalent to that of Arden, but I like the graphic notation of the relevant languages between states. You probably should not ask us about which method to study, but rather your instructor, if you have one.

Comment: @HendrikJan Thank You for the link, i should have been clear in the op. What i meant was " is the result of GNFA and Arden method same", which i learned it is from your comment and the link

Thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have added a reference that explicitly compares methods for transforming automata into expressions in a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacques Sakarovitch studies the outcome of the various algorithms.
See his paper *The Language, the Expression, and the (Small) Automaton* (CIAA 2005. LNCS 3845), where some results are summarized that are obtained in his book on automata theory. https://doi.org/10.1007/11605157_2

First one should note that the expression (and its size) highly depends on the *order* of handling the nodes, and not on the method.

When following strict methods (no additional tricks and shortcuts) the results seem syntactically equal. As far as I understand this result (from the paper) compares state elimination and Arden's solving equations.

> Proposition 1. The state elimination method and the solution (by
> Gaussian elimination) of a system of linear equations taken from an
> automaton give the same regular expression (assuming that the same
> order in elimination is used in both cases).

Comment: Perfect, This is what i wanted to know :)

Appreciate it